# WCF Integration Facility and Self-Hosted Services

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor

I'm self-hosting several services where I do this to register the service:

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
host.Open();
```

Behind the scenes, wcf instantiates my service via the default constructor.

Is it possble to use the WCF Integration Facility of Castle Windsor to get WCF to call on Windsor to create the service when I am self-hosting?

The example seems shows IIS hosted services where the 1st line of the MyService.svc file looks like:

```
<%@ServiceHost language=c# Debug="true" 
     Service="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService" 
     Factory=WindsorServiceHostFactory%>
```

where presumably a factory is used by wcf to instantiate the service instance.

Comment: actually, the factory is used to instantiate the one instance of the `ServiceHost`. That host will then create service class instances as needed to handle the incoming requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be helpful:
[How to host a WCF service that uses Castle Windsor in a Windows Service](http://mshelp.be/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-that-uses-castle-windsor-in-a-windows-service-247.htm)

But if it isn't, then I suggest you try asking on [the castle user forum](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users).

Comment: Thanks, this is almost exactly what I need. Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

With Castle 3.0, the way to do this is as follows:

```
// setup IoC, including registering the WcfFacility from Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
// and all other registrations you need
```

And then, assuming you have the necessary details in your `app.config` or are fine with the defaults:

```
// T is an interface with a backing service implementation registered in your IoC
public static ServiceHostBase StartHostService<T>(string serviceUrl)
{
    var assemblyQualifiedName = typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    var serviceHost = new DefaultServiceHostFactory()
        .CreateServiceHost(assemblyQualifiedName, new[] { new Uri(serviceUrl) });
    serviceHost.Open();

    return serviceHost;
}
```